# Interaction of include commands and target specific variables in make

Tags: makefile

Here is my makefile, essentially trying to work around the fact that target-specific variables aren't available in prereqs:

```
horse: shoe
    $(info Making horse)

clean:
    @rm -f horse nail shoe shoe.d

# Target-specific variable
shoe: DEPS := nail

shoe: shoe.d
    $(info Making shoe)
    @touch shoe

shoe.d:
    $(info Making shoe.d)
    @echo shoe: $(DEPS) > shoe.d

nail:
    $(info Making nail)
    @touch nail

-include shoe.d
```

If I run this:

```
$ make
Making shoe.d 
Making shoe
Making horse
```

It forgot the horseshoe nail! Turns out that shoe.d was created as if $DEPS wasn't set when the rule was run

```
$ cat shoe.d 
shoe:
```

I found two different tweaks that make things work (while destroying the point) that prove I really don't understand what's going on.

1) If I edit the Makefile to remove the last (include) line it still forgets the nail, of course, but now shoe.d is created correctly:

```
$ make clean
$ make
Making shoe.d 
Making shoe
Making horse
$ cat shoe.d 
shoe: nail
```

Putting the include line back and relying on the contents of shoe.d from the last invocation everything then works as expected:

```
$ make
Making nail
Making shoe
Making horse
```

Similarly, if I replace the include line with the rule written out explicitly, things always work as expected.

2) If I remove the target-specific nature of the DEPS variable, ie just write

```
DEPS := nail
```

then things work even with the include in place.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shoe.d` is being created as a result of make [remaking the makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) before making the targets, not as a result of considering the dependencies of `shoe`, so the recipes for `shoe.d` during this preliminary invocation don't inherit `shoe`'s target-specific variables (i.e. it's as if you invoked `make shoe.d`).

Make won't know that `shoe.d` is a makefile in the case if 1) and won't try to remake it before considering the targets, so it's created as a result of the normal dependency flow and inherits `DEPS` from `shoe`, for 2) on the other hand `DEPS`' value is set for the entire makefile.